# remove values around raster

Tags: raster, nodata

I'm working on QGIS 2.14. 
I'm using `grass7:neighbors` algorithm but i get artefacts on some sides of my images[image]

I would like to clip my new image with the shape of the original to remove this problem, but as I use `Vector -> Research -> Polygon from Layer` I'm getting the boundaries as a rectangle like this
[image]

I succeeded getting the boundaries by reclassifying pixels values (outside raster values seems to have value 1) and then vectorize the raster. I tried to cut my first raster with those boundaries, but it's not working and I still get the rectangle when i try `Vector -> Research -> Polygon from Layer`.

When I try `Raster->Convert` and set the nodata value to 1 I get this[image]

When I try the saga reclassification, and set values from 0.9 to 1 = 0/0 , I just get the rectangle filled with black.

Is there a way to tatally remove those values and to make them as the rest of the canvas ? (I don't want to give them another value because it would interfere with the grass:neighbors algorithm). Is ther a place where I can find what is the nodata value of my raster?